# Why alert is worked, but music dont' stop?

Tags: javascript, joomla

My js code, I have with code. When I use it the alert is worked when founded music, but the music is not stoped?

```
function myEvent() {

    // Функция stop для Audio:
    HTMLAudioElement.prototype.stop = function()
    {
      this.pause();
      this.currentTime = 0.0;
    }

    // myaudio.stop(); // использование


    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len;i++){
        if(audios[i]  != 0 || audios[i].playing()){
            alert("video");
            audios[i].pause();
            audios[i].stop();
        }
    }

    console.log('My Event!');

    jq_QuizNextOn();

}
```

Comment: Are there any javascript errors seen in the browser Developer Console? Besides that this logic `if(audios[i]  != 0 || audios[i].playing())` could better be `if(audios[i]  && audios[i].playing())`

Comment: I would assume that your `if` always passes, as audios[i] will never be zero.  So you get an alert for each audio regardless of whether it's playing.

Comment: When i use if(audios[i]  && audios[i].playing()) , i receive audios[i].playing is not a function

Comment: Hi, this link to quiz <a href="staracm8.beget.tech/…> <img src="habrastorage.org/webt/60/8f/c6/608fc678c9606637650466.png" alt="image"/> <img src="habrastorage.org/webt/60/8f/c6/608fc694da969358415762.png" alt="image"/> First screen- start quiz, second screen- button to stop music. Work only in Chrome